# image upload Query method in retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

that is my api

```
   http://192.168.0.2/littlezebra/scripts/webservice.php?Case=updateProfile&user_id=1&profile_picture=happychild.png
```

how to upload in and image same time in profile image

Comment: What does the entry point accept? Multipart file or byte array?

Comment: multi part file  accept